# Paho Mqtt Android client is not receiving any message in Android

Tags: android, mqtt

I have Mqtt Android client with following code source

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

import org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttAndroidClient;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.IMqttActionListener;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.IMqttDeliveryToken;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.IMqttToken;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttCallbackExtended;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttConnectOptions;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttException;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttMessage;

import java.util.Arrays;

import horseman.four.com.unite.app.UniteApp;
import horseman.four.com.unite.screens.map.ChatManager;
import horseman.four.com.unite.screens.map.model.ChatMessage;
import horseman.four.com.unite.screens.map.model.ChatModel;

/**
 * Created by Mahendra Chhimwal on 18/1/17.
 */

public class MqttManager implements MqttCallbackExtended {

    public static final String TAG = "MqttManager";

    private MqttAndroidClient mMqttAndroidClient;
    private MqttAndroidClient mMqttAndroidReceiver;

    private final String mServerUri = "tcp://unitevm.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com:1883";

    private String mClientId = null;
    private final String mSubscriptionTopic = "exampleAndroidTopic";
    private final String mPublishTopic = "exampleAndroidPublishTopic";
    private final String mPublishMessage = "Hello World!";

    private ChatManager mChatManager;
    private Context mContext;
    private String mTopic;

    private static Gson GSON = new Gson();

    private MqttManager() {
        mContext = UniteApp.getContext();
    }

    public static MqttManager getINST() {
        return new MqttManager();
    }

    public void setChatManager(@NonNull ChatManager chatManager) {
        mChatManager = chatManager;
    }

    @SuppressLint("HardwareIds")
    public void initConnection(String topic) {
        mTopic = topic;
        mClientId = Settings.Secure.getString(mContext.getContentResolver(),
                Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
        mMqttAndroidClient = new MqttAndroidClient(mContext, mServerUri, mClientId);
        mMqttAndroidReceiver = new MqttAndroidClient(mContext, mServerUri, "csajcbjsc");
        mMqttAndroidClient.setCallback(this);
        mMqttAndroidReceiver.setCallback(this);
        connectToServer();
    }

    @Override
    public void connectComplete(boolean reconnect, String serverURI) {
        if (reconnect) {
            Log.d(TAG, "reconnect is true . So subscribing to topic again");
            // Because Clean Session is true, we need to re-subscribe
            subscribeToTopic();
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Connected to MQTT server");
        }
    }

    private void connectToServer() {

        MqttConnectOptions mqttConnectOptions = new MqttConnectOptions();
        mqttConnectOptions.setAutomaticReconnect(true);
        mqttConnectOptions.setCleanSession(false);
        mqttConnectOptions.setKeepAliveInterval(300);
        mqttConnectOptions.setMqttVersion(MqttConnectOptions.MQTT_VERSION_3_1);
        try {
            mMqttAndroidClient.connect(mqttConnectOptions, null, new IMqttActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "mqtt connect successfull. Now Subscribing to topic...");
                    subscribeToTopic();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
                    if (exception != null) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "connect failure with exception : " + exception.getMessage());
                        exception.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

        } catch (MqttException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();

        }





        MqttConnectOptions mqttConnectOption = new MqttConnectOptions();
        mqttConnectOption.setAutomaticReconnect(true);
        mqttConnectOption.setCleanSession(false);
        mqttConnectOption.setKeepAliveInterval(300);
        mqttConnectOption.setMqttVersion(MqttConnectOptions.MQTT_VERSION_3_1);
        try {
            mMqttAndroidReceiver.connect(mqttConnectOptions, null, new IMqttActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "mqtt connect successfull. Now Subscribing to topic...");
                    subscribeToTopic();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
                    if (exception != null) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "connect failure with exception : " + exception.getMessage());
                        exception.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

        } catch (MqttException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void connectionLost(Throwable cause) {
        if (cause != null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Connection to MQtt is lost due to " + cause.getMessage());
        }
        // connectToServer();
    }

    @Override
    public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage message) throws Exception {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message arrived : " + message + " from topic : " + topic);
        if (mTopic.equals(topic)) {
            String text = message.toString();
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(text)) {
                handlerChatMessage(text);
            }
        }
    }

    private void handlerChatMessage(String message) {
        try {
            ChatModel chatModel = GSON.fromJson(message, ChatModel.class);
            if (chatModel.isChat()) {
                String chatMessage = chatModel.getMessage();
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(chatMessage)) {
                    ChatMessage cMessageObj = GSON.fromJson(chatMessage, ChatMessage.class);
                    cMessageObj.setSenderId(chatModel.getSender());
                    if (mChatManager != null) {
                        mChatManager.chatMessageArrived(cMessageObj);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken token) {
        try {
            if (token != null && token.getMessage() != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Message : " + token.getMessage().toString() + " delivered");
            }
        } catch (MqttException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private void subscribeToTopic() {
        try {
            mMqttAndroidClient.subscribe(mTopic, 0, null, new IMqttActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Subscribed to topic : " + mTopic);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "topic subscription failed for topic : " + mTopic);
                }
            });

        } catch (MqttException ex) {
            System.err.println("Exception whilst subscribing");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public void publishMessage(String messageText) {

        try {
            MqttMessage message = new MqttMessage();
            message.setPayload(messageText.getBytes());
            message.setQos(2);
            mMqttAndroidClient.publish(mPublishTopic, message);
            if (!mMqttAndroidClient.isConnected()) {
            }
        } catch (MqttException e) {
            System.err.println("Error Publishing: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Adb logs for publish event from client

```
01-21 02:03:47.581 17426-18022/horseman.four.com.unite D/AlarmPingSender: Register alarmreceiver to MqttServiceMqttService.pingSender.aae59bad799dafed
01-21 02:03:47.581 17426-18021/horseman.four.com.unite D/AlarmPingSender: Register alarmreceiver to MqttServiceMqttService.pingSender.csajcbjsc
01-21 02:03:47.620 17426-17426/horseman.four.com.unite D/MqttManager: mqtt connect successfull. Now Subscribing to topic...
01-21 02:03:47.632 17426-17426/horseman.four.com.unite D/MqttManager: mqtt connect successfull. Now Subscribing to topic...
01-21 02:03:47.895 17426-17426/horseman.four.com.unite D/MqttManager: Subscribed to topic : example_topic
01-21 02:03:48.250 17426-17426/horseman.four.com.unite D/MqttManager: Subscribed to topic : example_topic
01-21 02:03:54.859 17426-17426/horseman.four.com.unite D/MqttManager: Message : jcjcf delivered
01-21 02:03:56.087 17426-17426/horseman.four.com.unite D/MqttManager: Message : vjchxhf delivered
01-21 02:03:57.407 17426-17426/horseman.four.com.unite D/MqttManager: Message : jcjcufi delivered
01-21 02:03:58.342 17426-17426/horseman.four.com.unite D/MqttManager: Message : jchxuf delivered
01-21 02:03:59.267 17426-17426/horseman.four.com.unite D/MqttManager: Message : gjcjf delivered
01-21 02:04:00.089 17426-17426/horseman.four.com.unite D/MqttManager: Message : gjcig delivered
01-21 02:04:01.004 17426-17426/horseman.four.com.unite D/MqttManager: Message : gjcif delivered
01-21 02:04:01.819 17426-17426/horseman.four.com.unite D/MqttManager: Message : gjgiy delivered
01-21 02:04:02.839 17426-17426/horseman.four.com.unite D/MqttManager: Message : gjgiy delivered
01-21 02:04:03.457 17426-17426/horseman.four.com.unite D/MqttManager: Message : gjfjg delivered
01-21 02:04:04.378 17426-17426/horseman.four.com.unite D/MqttManager: Message : gjfiu delivered
01-21 02:04:21.478 17426-17426/horseman.four.com.unite D/MqttManager: Message : vghbng v gjc delivered
01-21 02:04:22.912 17426-17426/horseman.four.com.unite D/MqttManager: Message : bvcucjh delivered
01-21 02:04:24.140 17426-17426/horseman.four.com.unite D/MqttManager: Message : gjcjv delivered
```

Can any one please help me find out what I am missing here? The receiver is not receiving any message as it is seen clearly from logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are subscribed to `example_topic` (or whatever you set through `initConnection()` to `mTopic`) but you are publishing to `exampleAndroidPublishTopic` which is a fixed value of const `mPublishTopic`.

Comment: Hi @Pavel Zdenek just one more question. Client is receiving own published message as well. Is it valid mqtt behavior?

Comment: MQTT broker does not care who is the client. It's subscribed, it gets the message. So "valid" yes. But practical? Maybe for some kind of app event bus. But it's not a typical MQTT use case.